# How to implement DFS by hand in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I would like to implement by hand a simple DFS preorder traversal of a tree in [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/).  As a toy example, here is a simple tree:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
T = nx.generators.balanced_tree(2, 3)
nx.draw_networkx(T)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As this is a binary tree, I should in principle be able to perform a preorder traversal with something like:

```
def preOrder(root):
    if root:
        print(root.data)
        preOrder(root.left)
        preOrder(root.right)
```

However, I can't see how to do this in networkx.   How do I find the root and what is the networkx version of node.left and node.right?

---

## Update 1

In networkx there is `list(nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(T, source=r, depth_limit=1))` which treats the tree as an undirected graph and finds all the children from `r` which it treats as the root. I don't see how to use this, for example, to mimic node.left and node.right to perform the preorder traversal. It will for example give `[0,3,4]` if `r = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Networkx allows you varied ways to [traverse](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/traversal.html) nodes of a graph.  In your case you could use `dfs_preorder_nodes` and limit depth to `1`:

```
>>> G = nx.path_graph(5)
>>> list(nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(G, source=0))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(G, source=0, depth_limit=1))
[0, 1]
```

Note the API:

> If a source is not specified then a source is chosen arbitrarily and
>   repeatedly until all components in the graph are searched.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have the concept of parent and children. E.g. `list(nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(T, source=1, depth_limit=1))` gives `[1, 0, 3, 4]`

Comment: @Anush in your example it gave you all the children of the parent node.

Comment: Oh I see, it took 1 to be the root.  Then I am not sure how to use this to implement the DFS. I need the equivalent of node.left and node.right for each node in the tree.